# Python Selenium - How to handle alert that doesn't show up until after WebDriverWait finishes?

Tags: python, selenium, exception, alert

Currently I'm trying to automate an order process and at some point, if an order has been recently placed, an alert will pop-up stating, "Customer has placed an order for these same items within 2 days. Please check for duplicates or check Override Duplicate Order to continue."

I've tried the following to intercept that alert and allow the script to continue running:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.alert import Alert
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ExCon
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException, NoAlertPresentException,\
     UnexpectedAlertPresentException

from oleaprocs import Order

"""
    Will put the following constants in their own file later
"""
GEN_NEXT_ID      = "cmdNext"

SHIP_DET_METH_ID = "cboAvailItemsShip"
SHIP_DET_NEXT_ID = "cmdNext"

ORDER_REP_ID     = "cboServiceRep"

EMAIL_ID         = "ctl00_ctl00_main_content_main_content_ctl00_txtEmail"
SEARCH_RESULT_ID = "ctl00_ctl00_main_content_main_content_ctl00_dgResults_ctl03_lnkCustName"
ADD_ORDER_ID     = "cmdAddNewOrder"

LOGIN_ID  = 'ctl00_ctl00_main_content_main_content_ctl00_UserName'
PASS_ID   = 'ctl00_ctl00_main_content_main_content_ctl00_password'
SIGNIN_ID = 'ctl00_ctl00_main_content_main_content_ctl00_SigninBtn'

PLACED_VIA  = 'Phone'
BILL_OPTION = 'Visa x1111'

username = 'user'
password = 'pass'

customer = 'user'
items    = {'Item1': '100', 'Item2': '125'} # One or many items - also noting quantity

# This setup will likely be steamlined to determine whose server to use, etc
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("website-placeholder-for-security-reasons")

# Login will be separated out into a function, to allow for various logins
# log-in
driver.find_element_by_id(LOGIN_ID).send_keys(username)
driver.find_element_by_id(PASS_ID).send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_id(SIGNIN_ID).click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[text()="Customers"]').click()

# Type in search for user-email - separated to function later
search_email = driver.find_element_by_id(EMAIL_ID)
search_email.send_keys(customer)
search_email.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

# Click the (hopefully) singular search result
driver.find_element_by_id(SEARCH_RESULT_ID).click()
#search_result = driver.find_element_by_id(SEARCH_RESULT_ID).click()
#search_result.click()

### Start creating new order ###

## Order Items ##

# Accept Customer Orders alert
"""
alert_obj = driver.switch_to.alert
alert_obj.accept()
"""
Alert(driver).accept()

# Click on "Add New Order"
driver.find_element_by_id(ADD_ORDER_ID).click()

order = Order(driver)

# Set Placed Via
placed_via = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('cboPlacedVia'))
placed_via.select_by_visible_text(PLACED_VIA) # could also set IDs in a dict

# Set Billing Option
bill_option = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('ctrlBillOption$cboBillOption'))
bill_option.select_by_visible_text(BILL_OPTION)

# Add items to order
order.add_items(items)

# Will likely do some assertions here at some point, for custom / printed items

driver.find_element_by_id('cmdNext').click()

## Shipping Details ##

# Select Shipping Method

# If similar order recently placed - confirm alert and try/except duplicate order override

# driver.implicitly_wait(2)

try:
    print("WebDriverWait - 2 seconds")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 2).until(ExCon.alert_is_present())
    Alert(driver).accept()
    print("Switching to Alert")
    #alert_dupe = driver.switch_to.alert
    # print(str(alert_dupe.text))
    # alert_dupe.accept()

except TimeoutException:
    print("Timeout")

except NoAlertPresentException:
    print("No Alert Present")

except UnexpectedAlertPresentException:
    print("Unexpected alert, yo!")

try:
    driver.find_element_by_id('chkDuplicateOrderOverride').click()

except NoSuchElementException:
    print("No duplicate order detected")


# Continue
driver.find_element_by_id('cmdNext').click()

## Order Group Details ##

# Check for Authorize button (I could bypass this when I implement "order_type" later
try:
    driver.find_element_by_id('cmdAuthorize').click()
except NoSuchElementException:
    print("No Authorize Element Found - This payment method does not require authorization")

driver.find_element_by_id('cmdPlaceOrder').click()
```

And the other file referenced:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

"""
    Order will be used to keep track of the state of an order throughout
    the order-process. This can include things like the order total, items
    included, and can even get as complicated as 1:1 mirroring all of the
    details of an order. This will depend on our requirements.
"""
class Order(object):

    def __init__(self, driver):
        self.driver = driver

        # self.product_name_field = self.driver.find_element_by_id('txtProductName')
        # self.quantity_field = self.driver.find_element_by_id('txtQuantity')
        # self.add_item_button = self.driver.find_element_by_id('cmdAddSaveItem')


    # Add items to an order
    def add_items(self, items):
        """
            Will need to make the quantity check in here.
        """
        # product_name_field = self.driver.find_element_by_id('txtProductName')
        # quantity_field = self.driver.find_element_by_id('txtQuantity')
        # add_item_button = self.driver.find_element_by_id('cmdAddSaveItem')

        """
            Cannot simply one-time set the above because of the references
            going stale x_x - need to see if I can ignore stale-references.
        """
        for item, quantity in items.items():
            product_name_field = self.driver.find_element_by_id('txtProductName')
            product_name_field.send_keys(item)
            product_name_field.send_keys(Keys.TAB)

            quantity_field = self.driver.find_element_by_id('txtQuantity')
            quantity_field.send_keys(quantity)
            quantity_field.send_keys(Keys.TAB)

            add_item_button = self.driver.find_element_by_id('cmdAddSaveItem')
            add_item_button.click()
```

I made a comment about the previous alert potentially not releasing resources... I have the following code a good bit earlier to handle an alert that *always* pops up, so I don't have to `try` that one:

```
alert_obj = driver.switch_to.alert
alert_obj.accept()
```

I use the `driver.switch_to.alert` variation here because I've tried *both* variations in the earlier code and neither worked.

Basically what happens when the code gets to `WebDriverWait(drive, 2)`... is that the browser sits there and waits 2 seconds, *THEN* the alert pops up. I've tried various arbitrary lengths of time and it will always wait that amount of time, then show the alert. I feel like I'm being trolled here :|

Here is the error info I receive after this happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\Selenium\proj.py", line 136, in <module>
    driver.find_element_by_id('cmdAuthorize').click()
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 353, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 957, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 314, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 241, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace, alert_text)
selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedAlertPresentException: Alert Text: None
Message: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : Customer has placed an order for these same items within 2 days. Please check for duplicates or check Override Duplicate Order to continue.}
  (Session info: chrome=66.0.3359.181)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.38.552522 (437e6fbedfa8762dec75e2c5b3ddb86763dc9dcb),platform=Windows NT 10.0.16299 x86_64)
```

Any idea why this might be occurring? If I recall correctly, I don't believe we really have any alerts that also have checkboxes or input, so I wouldn't be 100% opposed to just 100% blocking alerts from being acknowledged by Selenium (or auto-accepting them), but I would like to avoid that if I can.

The code runs completely fine and places an order all the way through properly if no order has been placed recently (or I use a different account to test the order creation under over and over).

The manual steps from the point of adding items (just before the problematic page) would be:

1) Enter item name, then enter the item quantity
2) Do this for each item in the "items" dict
3) Hit the next button
4) Next page with shipping options "loads"
5) Issue occurs if an order was recently placed -- the WebDriverWait seems to be halting the loading of the page? It seems like this is the case since the alert will not show up until after the WebDriverWait time runs out.

I'm not really doing anything special after telling Selenium to hit the next button to reach the next page. Nothing different from the previous "hit the next button" actions, and the page shouldn't really be behaving any different than the other pages - even though the Alert is apparently just not having it x_x

Comment: Your code is `driver.find_element_by_id('chkDuplicateOrderOverride').click()` but traceback says `driver.find_element_by_id('cmdAuthorize').click()` ... Am I missing something?

Comment: Right? Super weird. So apparently it... just skips past a bunch of things and moves on to the next bit of code, and I've no clue why that happens, either. But it definitely stops there because at the 'cmdAuthorize' stage, we're already on the next page, so naturally it's trying to reference something that's not there.

It's a bit of a mess at the moment due to "notes to self", etc, but if you think it would help, I could post all of the code.

Comment: IMO too many `try{}` and `catch{}` are misbehaving. Can you update the question with a bit more of your _usecase (Manual Steps)_ and _code attempts_?

Comment: Updated with full code & some explication of the manual steps in the process. Kinda (I thought) straightforward, but here we are...

Answer (score 1):

I didn't have a "click next button" before the alert check -- the alert doesn't pop up until *after* I try and submit the shipping details *first*. Reason why it seemed to continue on to further steps after the alert-check failure.

Outline the process beforehand, kids.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the detailed solution